# Datastax error: Mismatch between Solr key field id with type text and Cassandra key alias key with type text

Tags: database, solr, cassandra, information-retrieval, datastax-enterprise

I use DataStax Enterprise 3.2. When running the example on http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.0/solutions/dse_search_load_data

There is an error in step 2, insert value key shall be string like, '123'.

Everything works fine until step 8. When I run,

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=mykeyspace.mysolr"
```

I got errors,

```
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">500</int><int name="QTime">229</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">Unable to create core: mykeyspace.mysolr</str><str name="trace">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core: mykeyspace.mysolr
....
....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mismatch between Solr key field id with type text{class=org.apache.solr.schema.TextField,analyzer=org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain,args={class=solr.TextField}} and Cassandra key alias key with type text
    at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.Cql3CassandraSolrSchemaUpdater.validateUniqueKeyStructure(Cql3CassandraSolrSchemaUpdater.java:226)
    at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.Cql3CassandraSolrSchemaUpdater.update(Cql3CassandraSolrSchemaUpdater.java:39)
    at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.core.CassandraCoreContainer.create(CassandraCoreContainer.java:282)
    ... 29 more
```

Am I missing some configuration? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Solr "text" (solr.TextField) type is really tokenized text which has no single, unique value for a sequence of tokens, while the Cassandra "text" type corresponds to the single-valued Solr "string" (solr.StrField) type.

This exception is alerting you to the likelihood that you should be using the Solr "string" type to match the Cassandra "text" type.

I just checked the doc link you gave and I do in fact see that the "id" field has type "string". Did you manually enter the incorrect type, as "text" rather than "string"?